# Python: Appending multiple data into one list using multiple loops

Tags: python, xml, csv, append

I'm trying to parse and store data from XML into an CSV file.

I have many multiple *repeated* child roots which force me to loop over instances and store them before writing. However, I'm trying to do something seemingly simple which is appending many multiple tags into the same list so I can writerows into the CSV file as one row.

Here are some snippets of my loop:

```
writer = csv.writer("input xml file name", dialect = 'excel')

data = []

for item1 in pat:
  if item1.find("name"):
    name = item1.find("name").text
    date = item1.find("date").text

    data.append((name, date))

for item2 in app:
  if item2.find("country"):
    country = item2.find("country")

    data.append((country))

for d in data:
  writer.writerow((d[0], d[1], d[2]))
```

Now I actually know this doesn't input the last d[2] entry because the "string index out of range" and does not show up as anything if I print the list.

I've also tried using **data.extend((country))** as well but to no avail; it simply gives me the same out of index range error.

Is there a way I can continue adding to the list data? The first two entries "name" and "date" work fine but I need another couple of loops to iterate over even more repeated tags than just country so I'd need a general method.

Here's the output I want:

```
Name        Date          Country
John Wid    2001-05-06    US
M. Pidd     2002-06-10    JP
Jimmy J.    2017-05-06    (Blank space)
Cool guy    2011-05-06    (Blank space)
```

Because "Country" only appears in "app" *sometimes*, each loop might only come up with only 1 or 2 countries and leave the rest blank whereas "Name" and "Date" might come up more times than that. This is why I have some areas saying (Blank space).

It may seem confusing but it's really just a matter of being formatted this way in the XML document.

Input looks like this where the "patcit" is the "pat" loop and "us-field-of-classification" is the "app" loop:

```
.
.
<patcit num="00001">
<document-id>
<doc-number>2292227</doc-number>
<kind>A</kind>
<name>Kopyto</name>
<date>19420800</date>
</document-id>
</patcit>
<category>cited by examiner</category>
<classification-national><country>US</country><main-classification>  2 67</main-classification></classification-national>
</us-citation>
<us-citation>
<patcit num="00002">
<document-id>
<doc-number>2437830</doc-number>
<kind>A</kind>
<name>McAllister</name>
<date>19480300</date>
</document-id>
</patcit>
<category>cited by applicant</category>
</us-citation>
<us-citation>
<patcit num="00003">
<document-id>
<doc-number>2450631</doc-number>
<kind>A</kind>
<name>Buchler</name>
<date>19481000</date>
</document-id>
</patcit>
.
.
.
.
<us-field-of-classification-search>
<classification-national>
<country>US</country>
<main-classification>D 2731</main-classification>
</classification-national>
<classification-national>
<country>US</country>
<main-classification>D 2742</main-classification>
</classification-national>
<classification-national>
<country>US</country>
<main-classification>D 2714</main-classification>
</classification-national>
<classification-national>
<country>US</country>
<main-classification>D 2738</main-classification>
</classification-national>
<classification-national>
<country>US</country>
<main-classification>D 2701</main-classification>
</classification-national>
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you add an extra empty list, you can append to that list

```
for item1 in pat:
  if item1.find("name"):
    name = item1.find("name").text
    date = item1.find("date").text

    data.append((name, date, []))

for item2 in app:
  if item2.find("country"):
    country = item2.find("country")

    data[-1][-1].append(country)
```

It may be easier to follow if you name the list though. Any reason not to do the second loop first?

Comment: I've tried both swapping the two loop's order along with deleting one of the loops to see which loop is the issue. So far nothing. Each loop works individually and appends the correct values but when put together gives an out of range error.

When I swapped the order it now states _"tuple index out of range"_

Comment: Also, after I swap the two loops I see that only d[0] works when the "app" loop is first whereas d[0] and d[1] both work when the "pat" loop is first. This means that the list "data" gives default indices based off the first loop's append. But using your data[-1][-1] method still gives an out of index...

Comment: @HelloToEarth, Since every item appended has 3 items, perhaps the IndexError is because there was no item appended by the first loop. Does the first loop always find exactly one match?

Comment: No, the first loop varies on how many instances of "name" and "date" it finds in the file, however, every instance finds the same number of names and dates. But, the amount of times it finds "country" is not the same as name or date.

For example, the first time around the XML file it finds 8 names and date but only 1 country.

Comment: @HelloToEarth, I don't really follow. Could you show representative input and output files in your question?

Comment: Hmm, possibly looking at the actual XML files should be the best bet. [XML FILES](https://bulkdata.uspto.gov/data/patent/grant/redbook/bibliographic/2017/) Just to check (if you can) you can see any of these XML files have the same format. My current code's output is shown up above when it works (for each instance of either loop because both in conjunction do not work) along with what I want it to look like.